# Connection between Eigenvectors and linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to understand the connection between Eigenvectors/Eigenvalues and linear equations:

$Ax=b$

If you are given the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A$, can you construct the solution for the linear equations?

Besides, if you are given the singular value decomposition of $A$ can you then construct the solution space for not square matrices?

Answer (score 4):

For a square matrix $A$, the equation $Ax = b$ will have a solution for every choice of $b$ if and only if $A$ is invertible.  That is, $Ax = b$ will have a solution for every choice of $b$ if and only if $0$ is *not* an eigenvalue of $A$.

In general, having the eigenvectors/eigenvalues of $A$ alone will not always help you find $A^{-1}b$.

Suppose that $A \in \Bbb F^{n \times n}$ is diagonalizable (i.e. has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors). Then we can say
$$
A = SDS^{-1}
$$
where $D$ is some diagonal matrix and $S$ is the matrix of eigenvectors.  Once we have all elements of this decomposition, we have
$$
A^{-1} = SD^{-1}S^{-1}
$$
where $D^{-1}$, being the inverse of a diagonal matrix, is really easy to compute.  That being said, finding $S^{-1}$ is not necessarily any easier than finding $A^{-1}$.

On the other hand, if $A$ satisfies $A^*A = AA^*$, then we can select an *orthonormal* set of eigenvectors, which means that our matrix $S$ will be *unitary*, i.e. we can find $S^{-1} = S^*$.  So, in this case, finding the decomposition may help since calculating the conjugate transpose of $S$ is much easier than inverting a matrix.  In particular, we would have
$$
A = SDS^* \implies A^{-1} = SD^{-1}S^*
$$
The singular value decomposition is definitely useful in this regard.  Suppose that $A$ has SVD $A = U\Sigma V^*$.  Then $Ax = b$ becomes
$$
U\Sigma V^* x = b \implies \Sigma (V^*x) = U^*b
$$
In this case, $\Sigma$ is diagonal, so it is very easy to solve the above for $V^*x$, from which we have $x = V(V^*x)$.

In fact, this idea of using a matrix's SVD is one way to arrive at the [Moore-Penrose inverse](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Singular_value_decomposition_.28SVD.29) of a matrix.

---

Let's look at the situation where $A \in \Bbb R^{m \times n}$ with $m < n$.  Suppose we know the SVD of $A$, so that $A = U \Sigma V^*$, where $U$ and $V$ are unitary, $U$ is $m \times m$ and $V n \times n$.  $\Sigma$ has the form
$$
\Sigma = 
\pmatrix{
\sigma_1 &&&|&\\
&\ddots & &|&0\\
&&\sigma_m &|
}
$$
Now, suppose we want to solve $Ax = b$. Let $c = U^* b$ and $y = V^*x$.  Then $Ax = b$ if and only if $\Sigma y = c$.  Once we solve for $y$, we can calculate $x = Vy$.

Suppose $c = (c_1,\dots,c_m)^T$.  The equation we now have is
$$
\pmatrix{
\sigma_1 &&&|&\\
&\ddots & &|&0\\
&&\sigma_m &|
} 
\pmatrix{
y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_n} = 
\pmatrix{
c_1 \\ \vdots \\ c_m
}
$$
That is, we have the system of equations
$$
\sigma_1 y_1 = c_1\\
\sigma_2 y_2 = c_2\\
\vdots \\
\sigma_m y_m = c_m
$$
Assuming every $\sigma_i$ is non-zero, we can take the solution $y_i = c_i/\sigma_i$ for each $i$ from $1$ to $m$ and $y_i = 0$ for $i > m$.

If any of the $\sigma_i$ are zero (with the corresponding $c_i$ non-zero), set the corresponding $y_i$ to $0$.  The resulting $y$ will no longer be a solution to the original problem, but it will be a "least squares solution".

From there, calculate $x = Vy$.

Comment: thank you very much. i'm interested in the case when A has less rows than columns. Why did you write V(V*x)?

Comment: Because we solved the above for $V^*x$, and since $V^* = V^{-1}$, we use $V$ to "undo" the $V^*$.  I'll expand to discuss the case you're interested in, if time permits.

Comment: @zuckerhut see my latest edit