# How to use eigenvalues and eigenvector to solve systems of linear equation

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A simple system of algebraic (not differential) equations such as:

$$ 3 x + 4 y - 8 z = 23 $$
$$ -2 x + 8 y - 11 z = -32 $$
$$ -4 x + 9 y - 32 z = - 8 $$

can be written as:
$$\mathbf{A} \vec x = \vec y$$

with, of course, the coefficients of $x$, $y$, and $z$ being arranged into a matrix $\mathbf A$ and the 23, -32, and -8 being arranged into a column vector $\vec b$.

My question is: How can we use eigenvectors and eigenvalues to solve for the vector $\vec x$ when the elements of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\vec y$ are known?

A couple of things:

- The StackExchange question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860411/connection-between-eigenvectors-and-linear-equations) somewhat addresses the issue,
  but the answer given is hard to follow because it goes off on
  tangents, and addresses far to much for me to find my answer in it. 
  The wikipedia page on eigenvectors and eigenvalues has the same
  problem.
- I am perfectly comfortable finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors, I just don't know how to use them to solve systems of linear equations.
- Most google searches that I have tried only show me how to solve systems of linear *differential* equations.
- I am aware that using eigenvalues and eigenvectors is not the usual (or easiest) method of solving systems of algebraic equations.
- I am familiar with the general interpretation of eigenvalues and eigenvectors as they pertain to rotating vector spaces, etc.

Comment: It doesn’t seem like chasing eigenvectors is the right approach for solving systems of linear equations since they’re really the answer to a different question. How does knowing that the transformation represented by the coefficient matrix is a simple scaling in a particular direction help you compute the intersection of three planes? The reason they’re useful in difference and differential equations is that you can then use superposition to construct a general solution from simple ones.

Comment: @amd Just following up on your comment, even in the context of linear difference/differential equations, when you go to find the coefficients in the formula for the general solution in order to solve some specific IVP/BVP, you still have to solve a linear system.

Comment: @Ian Indeed, but at that point you’re back to computing the intersection of a set of hyperplanes for which that system’s eigenvectors are of little use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general knowing the eigenvalues and eigenvectors (and generalized eigenvectors if applicable) does not really help you much with finding an exact solution to the linear system $Ax=b$, since it winds up writing the equation as $PJP^{-1}x=b$ where $P$ is the matrix of eigenvectors (and generalized eigenvectors if applicable) and $J$ is the Jordan form. If you were given $P$ and $J$ then you would proceed this way:

1. Solve $Py=b$.
2. Solve $Jz=y$.
3. Take $x=Pz$.

Generally speaking that first step is not any easier than solving $Ax=b$ was in the first place. It is easier if $A$ is normal (i.e. $A^*A = A A^*$ where $A^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $A$), because in this case $P$ is unitary so $y=P^* b$, but otherwise there is no particular reason to expect this to be easier. The remaining two steps are cheap by comparison.

When $A$ is not normal, the SVD is more useful for solving the linear system, even when $A$ is not normal, because all three matrices in the factorization are inexpensive to invert. The situation is similar for the QR decomposition.