# Let $A$ be a $3 \times 3$ symmetric matrix with three distinct eigenvalues $1, -1$ and $\lambda$. Find $\lambda$ and the corresponding eigenvector.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ be a $3 \times 3$ symmetric matrix with three distinct eigenvalues $1, -1$ and $\lambda$. We know that $Ax = 0$ where

$$x =\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

I try to find $\lambda$ and the corresponding eigenvector. Do you have any ideas how to approach this problem?

Comment: Try reading the definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Then compare it to $Ax=0$. Anything rings a bell?

Comment: You could start by setting up an arbitrary 3x3 symmetric matrix $A$ and setting the determinant of $A-tI$ to the polynomial $k(t-1)(t+1)(t-\lambda)$ [Of course A should satisfy also your condition about vector $[0,1,-1]^t.$

Comment: [Connection between Eigenvectors and linear equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860411/connection-between-eigenvectors-and-linear-equations)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Ax=0$ then $Ax=0×x$. So by *definition* of eigenvalue and eigenvector of a matrix $A$, it follows that $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ [because there is a vector namely $x$ such that $Ax=\lambda x=0×x$], and $x$ as stated is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda=0$.

Comment: Can we find directly $A$ in this problem?

Comment: Call the eigen vectors corresponding to 1 and -1 as (a,b,c) and (d,e,f). The eigen vectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are orthogonal. Solving x.y=0 for orthogonal vectors x and y we get the three eigen vectors. If P is the matrix of eigen vectors then $PDP^{-1}$ where D is the diagonal matrix of corresponding eigenvalues gives matrix A.

Comment: @eet the matrix $A$ is not uniquely determined by these conditions, there is more than one such $A$ that will work. A matrix that will work here would be...

Comment: $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\0 &-1/2 &-1/2\\0&-1/2&-1/2\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Here the eigenvectors are $[1,0,0]^{\top}$, $[0,1,1]^{\top}$, and  your aforementioned $x$.

Comment: So however would $A=\begin{bmatrix} -1&0&0\\0&1/2&-1/2\\0&1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I'm sorry the matrix should be instead $A=\begin{bmatrix} -1&0&0\\0&1/2&1/2\\0&1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix}$. Anyway $A$ as written also has the eigenvalues $\pm 1,0$.

Comment: @LawrenceMano yes, great. this was what I looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Mike thank you.